# how to create an insert script from a table using TOAD, oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I used TOAD for oracle 11g, I want  to create an insert script from a table. 
or I want to create a script file that allows  eclipse to rebuild the entire database with their data.

Comment: :Insert script can be saved from toad ,right click the data grid of the table and click save as (save grid content ) opened up then you can select how you want to retrieve the script

Comment: thx for answers ! i have found the solution :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the solution is :

`data base > schema browser`

then I select a table in :

```
> my schema > tables > my_table
```

to export the script to allow you to create your table :

> script > (copy past the `create table` part)

to export alla data :

```
>data > export dataset (blue icone) > export format : insert statement (and specify the output file)
```

then you can regroup the two script in a single script.sql (in order)

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Run your query Ex: `Select * from employee;`

In the table result grid > Click on '**Export grid Contents**' icon (Marked in yellow in the above image)

Select **Export Format** as '**Insert Statements**' > Click **OK**

You are done!

Answer (score 5):

**In Toad, there are database Level ICONS and Table Level ICONS.**

Database ICONS are those that appeaer at the top, just below (For Ex:  Toad For Oracle).

They begin from left to right, File/Edit/Search/Editor/Session....

Table level ICONS are those that appear when you have a table highlighted, or part of the data

grid, (when data appears for a table).

You can import from the Database ICONS, and you can export to a .dmp file

but you can't export to either SQL LOADER or INSERT STATEMENT from the database ICONS, so use the

table level ICONS.  See Following Steps:

A.

1. Highlight a table
2. Right Click on the table
3. Export Table
4. In Export Format:  Choose Insert Statements

OR

B.

When a table has data, and you have selected the Data Tab you will have below the

Column/Indexes/Constraints/Triggers/Data/Script tabs several ICONS, I.E. a filter Funnel,

and three ICONS to the right you will have a database icon (IN BLUE).

You can click on it, and choose your Export Format.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on a table in Schemabrowser -> Generate Statement -> Insert

Answer (score 0):

you can generate insert script using toad,write table name in toad and press F4 then right click on table name and select export data and then new window will open ,select export format as insert statement then file path to save,script will be generated at specified path.....